# PHP inbuilt server gives "CLI has stopped working"

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am trying to use the PHP inbuilt server feature `php -S localhost:8888` to run a testing server for a project of mine. When I use it, an error appears:

[image: Error message]

In the event log, the following error appears:

```
Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15e42
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.4.3.0, time stamp: 0x4fb15f2c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000119940
Faulting process id: 0x1a40
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce84b22074fc3f
Faulting application path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php5ts.dll
Report Id: 5e31c3a5-f0a5-11e2-b720-90e6bab78fd4
```

I have commented out (`;`) every PHP extension in php.ini one by one, and none of them made a difference. I even tried commenting every PHP extension out, but still no result. I have re-installed WAMP and updated it to the latest version, but this yields no results.

I do not have IIS installed or running, or any other services (aside from WAMP) running on port 80, and no services running on port 80.

My PHP version is 5.4.3, Apache is 2.4.2 running on WAMP 2.2e, Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: This would constitute a bug in the PHP core. 5.4.3 is now quite outdated, in fact [5.5.1 was released yesterday](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-07-18-1). Update your PHP version and if you still have a problem, [report a bug](http://bugs.php.net/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution (credit goes to DaveRandom) was to update PHP to version 5.5.1 following these steps:

1. Download 5.5.1 Windows Binaries.
2. Make new folder in {wamproot}/bin/php/ called "php5.5.1".
3. Replace all occurrences of "5.4.3" in {wamproot}/wampmanager.ini with "5.5.1".
4. Repeat step 3 for wampmanager.conf
5. Update PATH environment variable

Comment: Thank you so much! I broke my back on this on. I hope all my other problems that i started having since I upgraded to 5.4.3 will also disappear.

Comment: make a copy of php5.4.2, and make a copy of step 3 and 4. you may fall back anytime if you wish.