# cli has stopped working for php 7.1.9 xampp in windows 7

Tags: php, redis, xampp, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I have upgraded PHP version from **5.5** to **7.1.9** by re-installing **XAMPP**.In my project I am working on **laravel queue** with **Redis** server.

But, When I am trying to run queue work command by `php artisan queue:work --queue=high` for a job its show me a windows popup and nothing happening and terminal get stuck until I close that popup

[image]

I am not getting what is the issue.
I had done some research on this but my issue is not fixed with these solutions.
Ex:-
[PHP inbuilt server gives "CLI has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753910/php-inbuilt-server-gives-cli-has-stopped-working)
[PHP -> CLI has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working)

Any body have any solution please share with me.

**Error log in Apache**:-

```
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:51.928457 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:52.346464 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:53.156465 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:53.156465 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:53.156465 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:53.166465 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5244:tid 152] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6460
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:53.892473 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6460:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:54.062473 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6460:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:39:54.472474 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6460:tid 168] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.102212 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.392213 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.422213 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.422213 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  9 2017 11:48:22
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.422213 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.422213 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6832:tid 152] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7068
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:08.962214 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7068:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:09.132214 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7068:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 26 15:41:09.162214 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7068:tid 168] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Any error(s) in the apache logs that might offer any clues?

Comment: Yes I have errors check  this